# how to background color to pdf view in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview

I am creating the pdf using the following [tutorial](http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/) is works for me

but it shows white background of pdf i want to give color to the background how to do this

i have seen all the code but there is no any option in this to give color is there anyway to give color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside do while loop use these lines of code....
Here pdfpageFrame is the frame of your Pdfpage.

```
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(currentContext, [UIColor redColor].CGColor );
CGContextFillRect(currentContext, pdfpageFrame);
```

Comment: nice it works for os 4.2 but when i use this tutorial for 5.0 it is not showing file in documents folder i dont know what is the reason

Answer (score 0):

Just before the drawBorder, do this:

```
  CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(currentContext, [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor);
  CGContextFillRect(currentContext, pdfpageFrame);
```

Comment: have you seen the tutorial i want to ask something related that i am implementing in my another code then it does not create pdf i am using OS 5.0

Comment: The above answer was with respect to the tutorial you've mentioned... What they're doing is essentially use CoreGraphics to create the page, then export to PDF. The PDF is found in the documents directory, as he explains. :) See the drawPDF method he calls and how he writes it to Demo.pdf in http://www.ioslearner.com/convert-html-uiwebview-pdf-iphone-ipad/